# Class method not returning value in Python

Tags: python, class

I am having some trouble passing a variable into a function and having it return a desired value. For clarity, I am obtaining a record from a PostgreSQL table as a tuple and then passing the relevant index of that tuple into a class variable. Everything else seems to work but this and I have no idea why.

The code is as follows:

```py
from datetime import date
from decimal import Decimal
from config import config
import psycopg2


conn = None
try:
    params = config()
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM testdb.vitals ORDER BY "vitalsID"')

except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print(error)

row = cur.fetchone()


class Vitals:

    birth = date(1990, 12, 12)
    today = date.today()
    years = today.year - birth.year
    age = today.year - birth.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (birth.month, birth.day))
    weight = row[2]
    height = row[3]
    activity = row[4]
    goal = row[5]
    fatRatio = row[6]
    carbohydrateRatio = row[7]
    proteinRatio = row[8]

    def __init__(self):
        # connect and initialise vitals
        pass

    # display on gui

    @classmethod
    def activityText(cls):
        if cls.activity == Decimal(1.20):
            return testActivity * 2

    @classmethod
    def bmr(cls):
        return (Decimal(10) * cls.weight) + (Decimal(6.25) * cls.height) - (Decimal(5) * cls.age) + Decimal(5)

    @classmethod
    def tdee(cls):
        return Decimal(outputBmr * cls.activity)

    @classmethod
    def net(cls):
        if cls.goal == 1:
            return outputTdee - (outputTdee * Decimal(0.1))
        else:
            return outputTdee


importVitals = Vitals

testActivity = importVitals.activity
print(testActivity)

testActivityfunc = importVitals.activityText()
print(testActivityfunc)

outputBmr = round(importVitals.bmr())
print(outputBmr)

outputTdee = round(importVitals.tdee())
print(round(outputTdee))

outputNet = round(importVitals.net())
print(outputNet)

if importVitals.activity == Decimal(1.20):
    print('Hello')
else:
    print("\n")
    print(importVitals.activity)
    print(type(importVitals.activity))
```

The key class method is here:

```py
    @classmethod
    def activityText(cls):
        if cls.activity == Decimal(1.20):
            return testActivity * 2
```

Output (following alteration of the final if statement in the module) is as follows:

```py
1.20
<class 'decimal.Decimal'>
None
1751
2101
1891


1.20
<class 'decimal.Decimal'>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

For readability, here are the print statements:

```py
testActivity = importVitals.activity
print(testActivity)
print(type(importVitals.activity))

testActivityfunc = importVitals.activityText()
print(testActivityfunc)

outputBmr = round(importVitals.bmr())
print(outputBmr)

outputTdee = round(importVitals.tdee())
print(round(outputTdee))

outputNet = round(importVitals.net())
print(outputNet)

if importVitals.activity == Decimal(1.20):
    print('Hello')
else:
    print("\n")
    print(importVitals.activity)
    print(type(importVitals.activity))
```

The class method in question always returns `None`. Also note the if statement at the end of the module. It always runs the else branch which, at least to me, bizarrely prints `1.20` and `<class 'decimal.Decimal'>`. So if Python recognises the instanced class variable of `importVitals.activity` as having the value `1.20` and the variable type of `<class 'decimal.Decimal'>`, then why is the if statement or the class method not returning what I would like it to? Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Just to reiterate, all of the other methods and print statements are working as expected so I am quite puzzled by this.

Thank you to anybody who took the time to read this. I would appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: `if Vitals.activity == Decimal(1.20):` Shouldn't that be `if importVitals.activity == Decimal(1.20):`?

Comment: Hi Johnny. I used the class reference directly because I wanted to be sure that it was being passed correctly from the tuple to the class variable.

I just tried the alternative (with the instance of the class) but it returns the same result, unfortunately.

Comment: Since importVitals = Vitals, therefore importVitals is a pointer to Vitals, so it does not matter, I guess. But I suggest try importVitals.activity == Decimal(1.20)

Comment: @twelfth can you post your program's output?

Comment: Hi @nagyl. No problem; the OP has now been updated to include the output of the file and I have also changed the final if statement too as per your and Johnny Mopp's suggestion.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but why are you defining a class in the first place, and why `importVitals = Vitals`? (This just creates an additional reference to the class, not an instance of the class. They way the class is written, though, there is no *reason* to use an instance of the class instead of the class itself.)

Comment: @chepner since this class uses class methods and class variables, not self ones, it is correct to use it that way, but feels uneccessary.

Comment: @nagyl That's my point. Why define a class that you never intend to instantiate?

Comment: @chepner I am somewhat new to Python (and OOP in general) and thought it might be prudent as I reference this module in another module which uses the variables here listed to output to a GUI. As to the instance, I thought this was good practice but you are quite right that I could refer directly to the class.

Comment: @twelfth can you please add -> print(type(importVitals.activity)) right after your first print?

Comment: @chepner After we find the solution, I will add a sample of that to the answer!:)

Comment: @nagyl Thanks for the continued help. I have now added the additional print statement to the file, along with its resultant output (```<class 'decimal.Decimal'>```)

Comment: The problem is probably floating-point precision: `1.2 != Decimal('1.2')` (And if `activity` is the string `'1.2'`, that *certainly* is not equal to `Decimal('1.2')`.

Comment: No since both the objects are instance of Decimal, and I already checked that they handle minor differences between values.

Comment: When does `activity` become a `Decimal` value?

Comment: I am also looking for it, but according to it's output, it is an instance of Decimal. How does he fill the class with values?:D

Comment: @twelfth what cls refers to in your class?

Comment: @chepner Interesting development (perhaps). When the if statement is turned into ```importVitals.activity >= float(1.20)``` or ```importVitals.activity >= Decimal(1.20)```, it returns ```Hello```. So somehow, although it views the object of ```importVitals.activity``` as Decimal type, it must be some infinitessimal degree above that (due to floating point precision, as you suggest). In fact, even when I do the following: ```importVitals.activity >= Decimal(1.20) and importVitals.activity < Decimal(1.21)``` it returns ```Hello```.

Comment: @nagyl As to the type, I believe it might inherit this from PostgreSQL, maybe. In the database, the data type is numeric(6,2); see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-numeric.html) for more information. cls is, I believe, standard practice to refer to the class (or Vitals in this case). Apologies if I misunderstand your question.

Comment: @twelfth since you use class methods, and not initalize your variables inside your class, it is unnecessary.

Comment: @nagyl In that case, should I be using a static method instead?

Comment: There is a solution now, but may I add another one showing how should you use classes to represent objects? @twelfth

Comment: @nagyl Yes, I would very much appreciate that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have numeric errors:

```
>>> Decimal(1.20)
Decimal('1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875')
>>> Decimal("1.20")
Decimal('1.20')
```

Use strings as an input for your decimals and everything should be fine. Floats are good for fast computations, but they are not a good fit for accuracy.

Comment: Decimal(1.20) == 1.20, returns True. Decimal(1.20) == Decimal(1.20), also returns True.

Comment: @nagyl That's because you are creating a `Decimal` instance using the same `float` value you are comparing it against. `1.2` is *not* the rational number `12/10`.

Comment: Because you use floats across the board. It's not real 1.20 number, just inaccurate representation.

Comment: Ok, I missed that string 1.20 != float 1.20. I wouldn't use string for numbers.

Comment: The particular use case (to calculate TDEE) relies on discrete values; see [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Katch-McArdle-Multipliers-for-Calculating-TDEE_fig4_337655510). Consequently the ```activityText()``` method should turn ```activity``` into its corresponding string. In the ```tdee()``` method a calculation is performed. For this specific purpose, a rounding error may be permissible as it evaluates to 1 calorie more or less than the expected value, roughly. Rendering ```activity``` as a string for the purposes of the conditional works for this purpose. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more object oriented way to implement the above code:

```
import sys
import psycopg2

from datetime import date
from decimal import Decimal
from config import config

class Vitals:
    def __init__(self, row):
        self.birth    = date(1990, 12, 12)
        self.today    = date.today()
        self.years    = today.year - birth.year
        self.age      = today.year - birth.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (birth.month, birth.day))
        self.weight   = row[2]
        self.height   = row[3]
        self.activity = Decimal(float(row[4]))
        self.goal     = row[5]
        self.fatRatio = row[6]
        self.carbohydrateRatio = row[7]
        self.proteinRatio = row[8]

    def activityText(self):
        if self.activity == Decimal(1.20):
            return self.activity * 2
        
    def bmr(self):
        return (Decimal(10)   * self.weight) +
               (Decimal(6.25) * self.height) -
               (Decimal(5)    * self.age)    +
                Decimal(5)

    def tdee(self):
        return Decimal(self.bmr() * self.activity)

    def net(self):
        if self.goal == 1:
            return self.tdee() - (self.tdee() * Decimal(0.1))
        else:
            return self.tdee()

def getDataFromDatabase(sql):
    conn = None
    try:
        params = config()
        conn   = psycopg2.connect(**params)
        cur    = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(sql)
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
        return None
    return cur.fetchone()

def main():
    sql = 'SELECT * FROM testdb.vitals ORDER BY "vitalsID"'
    row = getDataFromDatabase(sql)
    vitals = Vitals(row)
    #Here you can do your stuff with vitals
    
main()
```

---

You can create more objects, and fill them with different values. I suggest cast the values of `row` in the constructor to proper types, like `activity` to Decimal.
I cannot guarantee this version would solve your initial problem, I tried another solution, but since the question has a proper answer, that wasn't my main goal.

---

I saw the post that you said a one calorie difference is acceptable, so I suggest creating a function, that has a treshold of one calorie, and if the `abs` of the difference between 2 objects is less than the treshold, return true.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for this. Is there a way I can mark two solutions? The 1st answer helps me directly with this problem but yours also helps me understand OOP much better. I have upvoted yours and other in either case.

Comment: Post a different question, and I'll copy this answer there! Here accept the other solution since it solved your initial problem.

Comment: I will post a link here once my timer has elapsed for posting again. Thanks for all of your help. Thanks also for the note regarding the 1 calorie threshold. I will add that in too!

Comment: When will that be?

Comment: I believe in about 5 or so minutes.

Comment: Post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63194031/module-is-unnecessarily-verbose-and-not-object-oriented-enough-what-makes-this)! Thanks again. I do have a few issues when running but I will bring those up in the relevant thread.

Comment: Hi @nagyl. Unfortunately I cannot mark your answer as the solution as stack overflow states the answer has been deleted. My apologies for that.

Comment: It has been removed since it is a duplication :(

Comment: Ah, sorry about that :( I do actually have a related question pertaining to how I might retrieve the attributes in a separate module. I shall post this shortly and link here too!

Comment: We can try, but it will still be a duplicate.

Comment: Hey @nagyl. My apologies but whilst I was waiting to be able to post again, I continued to fiddle around with the template you had given me and now everything works as intended. It imports from the class correctly and displays in the GUI. Apologies I could not accept your answer but thank you so much all the same.

Comment: Happy to help!!